# Creating arrays on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript

This has been eating me away. [Check CodePen here](https://codepen.io/blindpupil/pen/qmzpyb?editors=0011/). I have a function that adds elements to a ruler. Call expose.init(lengthOfPeriod) with an integer to set the length of each period in the ruler. Call expose.addAction(time, team) with an integer and a string == 'HOME' || 'AWAY' to place an action in the ruler.

When the screen is resized, I want something to happen to the elements in the ruler that touch each other (basically collapse into a group).

I have a function 'detectOverlap' that takes 2 params and determines if they are touching or not. I also have a function in the resize event handler that populates an array 'allTouching' with all the elements in the ruler that are touching each other at each resize.

```
if (actionArray.length > 1) { //don't run if there's only one element in the page
actionArray.reduce(function (prev, next) {
    if (detectOverlap(prev, next)) {
        if (allTouching.indexOf(prev, next) === -1) allTouching.push(prev, next);
    }
    return next;
});
```

If actions are touching each other, I need them to collapse into groups. In order to do this, I need to create an array for each group of actions touching each other. However, I haven't been able to make this happen so far.
Here's some pseudo code:

```
for (i = 0; i < allTouching.length; i++) {
  if (detectOverlap(allTouching[0], alltouching) { 
    touchingGroup[i] = new Array(allTouching[0], all other elements touched by 0);
    do not include any element more than once in touchingGroup[i];
    do not include any similar arrays (same elements) in allGroups;
    allGroups.push(touchingGroup[i]); 
  }
}
```

In short, this would need to loop for all the elements in the allTouching array, and create a new touchingGroup[n] for each new group of actions that touch each other.

This sounds simple in my head, and I'm sure there must be a way to do it without code getting overly complex, but I haven't found it yet. 
Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your question is only about the grouping, so I will ignore the visualisation aspect and assume that the function `detectOverlap` is correct.

Then you could create the groups in one `for` loop. In this snippet I have added simplistic sample data and a mock `detectOverlap` function that will return true when its two arguments are the same (just for the purpose of the snippet):

```js
// Simplistic mock data and function, just to make the snippet work
var actionArray = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9];
function detectOverlap(a, b) { return a === b; }

// Actual code:
var allGroups = [];
var start = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= actionArray.length; i++) {
    if (i >= actionArray.length || !detectOverlap(actionArray[i-1], actionArray[i])) {
        if (i - start > 1) // Remove this condition if you want singletons as well
            allGroups.push(actionArray.slice(start, i));
        start = i;
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(allGroups));
```

#### Explanation

The variable `start` is used as an index in the array, from where the most recently found group should start. That group is not yet actually created, since we do not know where it ends, and so I will call this the "undecided" group. `start` is initialised at 0 to indicate that the first group will start there.

The loop iterates over the array, but starting at 1. In each iteration it decides whether the "undecided" group (started at `start`) is complete. The group is considered complete when there is no overlap between the previous and the current element of the array. In that case the previous element is the last element of the "undecided" group. The elements for that group are copied from the array with `slice`. Note that the second argument of `slice` is the index of the first element that should *not* be part of the group. Now that group is stored, and `start` is put at the current index, where the next (and only) "undecided" group should start.

But as long as the two elements *do* overlap, no new group should be created (that is why the condition has a `!`). Instead `start` remains unchanged, and so this "undecided", "unclosed" group is getting bigger in size.

There is an `if` just before that `slice`, which prevents the creation of groups that only contain one element. If you remove that `if`, then also single elements will be isolated in their own "singleton" groups.

The loop will go up to and *including* `arrayAction.length`: this is unusual, since that makes the last *i* an invalid index. But it is useful, since in that case we still want to finish up the last group that is still "ongoing". So in that case `i >= arrayAction.length` will be true, and so the `detectOverlap` function will not be called (because the `if` condition is already known to be true). The `if` block will be entered and the final group will be created.

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks a lot. The only thing missing is a line to eliminate repeated arrays; since it's going to be called over and over when the screen is resized, allGroups will get cluttered with the same results like: Array [ Array[2], Array[3], Array[2], Array[3] ...

Comment: Make sure to do `allGroups = []` at every resize event, before doing the loop. However, when checking the results, you need to look at the sub arrays as well. `Array[2]` is not revealing what is actually *in* that array, so seeing `Array[2]` twice, does not mean they are the same array.

Comment: That's gorgeous, thank you. 
I'm just trying to understand the logic, and I'm lost in the first if statement: why are you checking for 'i' >= actionArray.length or NOT detectOverlap(...) ? From what I understand the first statement in this OR should always return false except when i and array.length are equal. And then, how is it even working if the second part of the OR checks NOT detectOveralap?

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer. Let me know if this clarifies it.

Comment: I see it clearly now, I was looking at it backwards before. Thank you very much!